# Eclipse Marketplace - Maven Integration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am in Eclipse Indigo and trying to install Maven Support for eclipse. I search Eclipse Marketplace with "maven" and found there are two entries:

- Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP.
- Maven Integration for Eclipse.

Now I am confused to choose them.

I am developing web application. So what is the entry I should go for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install them both. The first is specifically designed to integrate with WTP, the second one is general Maven integration in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to just use Maven? With Indigo, m2e is already integrated. If you look at eclipse.org, you will find there the following features integrated:

[image]

If you open the preferences in Eclipse (`Windows > Preferences`), you will find there the Maven configuration for Eclipse:

[image]

You have to configure there, where your Maven installation lives, and can start to use Maven inside Eclipse.

Comment: This is only included in the IDE for Java Developers package. The Java EE Developers package does not include maven support. Here is what is in each package http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php.

Comment: It was not obvious (at least for me) that the question was based on Java EE distro. Interesting link, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @mliebelt WTP stands for WebToolPlatform and relates to JEE stuffs